# Quotient Module is Not Free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity. If $a\in R, a \not = 0$, prove that $R/(a)$ is not a free $R$-module.

My initial attempt was to say that R/(a) is not torsion free, thus it cannot be free, but then I realized that the theorem "M is a free module if and only if it is torsion free" only works for finitely generated modules over PIDs.  So I'm pretty lost as to how to prove this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you want to look at annihilators of the whole module, not of individual elements.

Comment: what do i want to show about its annihilator?  Obviously, the annihilator of R/(a) will just be (a), so it is not zero.  Does this imply that R/(a) is not free?

Comment: It implies that it's free if you can show that $(a)$ is not the annihilator of any free module.  To start with, what's the annihilator of $R$?

Comment: the annihilator of R is all zero divisors in R (if we're considering R as a module over itself).

Comment: @MalcolmLazarow Not so.  Check the definition.

Comment: okay, so annihilator elements need to annihilate all elements, so the zero divisors will not necessarily be in the annihilator.  So let's assume that the annihilator of R is {0}?  What then?

Comment: @MalcolmLazarow Now how about the annihilator of a general free module $F=\bigoplus_{s\in S} Rs$?  If you want to take a shortcut, note that $F$ has a submodule isomorphic to $R$ if $F\neq 0$.

Comment: So $F=\oplus _{s\in S} Rs$ also has annihilator 0 because R has annihilator zero.  So then we can say: if M is free, then ann(M)={0}. and we can then say that if ann(M) =\= {0}, M is not free?

Comment: @MalcolmLazarow Yes, we can say all of these things.  And to be clear, the reason that $\operatorname{Ann}_R R=0$ is that nothing annihilates $1$.

Comment: ahhh, i see i see.  thanks @you-sir-33433 this is a lot clearer now!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sorry I'm late for this question, but since it is of my interest I would like to answer it anyway. If I understood correctly $(a)$ denote de $R$-module generated by $a\in R$, so $(a)=aR$. Suppose $[x]\in R/(a)$ is any element, so we have $[x]a=[xa]=[0]$, since $xa\in aR=(a)$. If I am not mistaken this proves that any subset of $R/(a)$ can not be linearly independent over $R$. Thus we conclude that $R/(a)$ can not be free over $R$.

Can anyone confirm if this is correct? Thanks.